# Groovy Eclipse Stubbed Method

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I have some groovy files in Eclipse and my project has the Groovy nature. I don't use the GroovyBuilder (I don't think you need to now. there were problems in the past when java files referenced groovy and vice versa). Sometimes when I run my project I get a "Stubbed Method" error and I need to do a project clean for the groovy files to rebuild. Any ideas why I need to do this and what causes the files to need rebuilding if I'm not changing them?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using an old version of the plugin.  Please upgrade to V2 of groovy-eclipse (still in alpha, but quite stable).

The update site is available here:
http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.5/

Also, be sure to convert all your old groovy projects to the new format (see the groovy preferences page).

Comment: It looks like that worked. I'll keep an eye out to see if it happens anymore though. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: And there are frequent updates to this plugin, so please check the update site regularly.  We are working towards a first milestone release towards the middle of September.